# Chinese character on WebSphere are not getting displayed

Tags: 2013, dd4t

In our dd4t java application we are dispalying some content in chainese language selector. All chanracter are getting displayed properly if we are deploying application on Tomcat. But Chainese character are not dispalying on WebSphere server. these are replaced by "??". Character encoding is set to UTF-8. Here is the response content type from browser.

```
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: The following two JVM parameters set in the WebSphere Application Server Administration Console will also override the character encoding type used by the application server. These parameters should only be used in the event the above approaches do not resolve the problem.

Change the JVM parameter back to -Dclient.encoding.override=UTF-8 Servers > Application servers > Java and Process Management > Process Definition > Java Virtual Machine > Generic JVM Arguments
-Dclient.encoding.override=UTF-8
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8.....